# How do I rename two files at the same time?

Tags: bash

So I want to rename two files at the same time. I tried this.

> mv {dog1,dog2}, {puppy1,puppy2}

Comment: It's not clear whether you expect `dog1` to be moved to `dog2` or to `puppy1`.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "at the same time"? In an atomic way? Or just want a one-liner?

Comment: I want dog1 to become puppy1 and dog 2 to become puppy2

Comment: So you want to set any answer as solution and thank the author this way?

Answer (score 5):

The question is whether the new names are arbitrary and unrelated, or whether they all have the same text replaced.

For the latter, various multi-rename tools can replace `dog` with `puppy` easily:

```
rename dog puppy dog1 dog2
perl-rename s/dog/puppy/ dog1 dog2
mmv "dog*" "puppy#1"
for file in dog1 dog2; do mv "$file" "${file/dog/puppy}"; done
```

(In all cases, `dog1 dog2` can be shortened to `dog[1-2]` or `dog?` or `dog*`.)

Comment: the first one didn't work, it said..Bareword "dog" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (user-supplied code).

Comment: the second one it said perl-rename command not found,

Comment: dog* -> puppy#1 : no match.
Nothing done.
that was for the third one

Comment: mv: missing destination file operand after 'puppy1'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing destination file operand after 'puppy2'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.

Comment: in your system, perl-rename is actually called `rename`

Comment: ok so I tried rename instead of perl-rename and I got this Substitution replacement not terminated at (user-supplied code).

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop for doing this:

```
for i in {1..2}; do mv "dog$i" "puppy$i"; done
```

Replace the `2` in the `{1..2}` by any positive number you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename two files at once:

```
mv dog1 dog2 && mv puppy1 puppy2
```

will only rename puppy1 if dog1 was renamed succesful

```
mv dog1 dog2; mv puppy1 puppy2
```

will always try to remove puppy1, no matter dog1 was renamed.

Comment: I tried the first one and it tells me puppy2 is not a directory

Comment: and I tried the second one and it tells me 'cannot stat puppy2'